# Problems on computing $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-[(2 m+1) \pi-i k] x}~dx $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I need help understanding these computations:

$$2 \int_{-\infty}^0 dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}} + 2 \int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}} = $$

$$2 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \left [\int_0^{\infty}dx \, e^{-[(2 m+1) \pi+i k] x} +\int_0^{\infty}dx \, e^{-[(2 m+1) \pi-i k] x} \right ] =$$

$$2 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \left [\frac{1}{(2 m+1) \pi-i k} + \frac{1}{(2 m+1) \pi+i k} \right ] $$

I just don't see how to write this as sums as done in the first equation. I tried using the sum formula/definition of the exponential function, but it does not get me to that formula at all.

The second equation is unclear too. I tried to calculate the second summand first:
$$\int_0^{\infty}dx \, e^{-[(2 m+1) \pi-i k] x} =$$

$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \left [ -\frac 1 {(2m+1)\pi +ik} e^{-((2m+1)\pi +ik)x} \right ]_0^r = $$

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \left [-\frac 1 {(2m+1)\pi +ik} e^{-((2m+1)\pi +ik)r} \right ] + \frac 1 {(2m+1)\pi +ik} $$

So the the limit has to evaluate to $0$. I really don't understand how that would be possible though, since $e^x$ never evaluates to $0$. And with $r \rightarrow \infty$ we are just circling around on the unit circle forever but it doesn't change anything, right?

Comment: In the limit, the exponent has negative real part as $r \to \infty$--recall that $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x} = 0$ (as you can see on a graph), and also $e^{ikr}$ is bounded, being on the unit circle.

Comment: Just find $\int_0^\infty e^{a x}dx$ for an alternate derivation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$L=\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \left [-\frac 1 {(2m+1)\pi +ik} e^{-((2m+1)\pi +ik)r} \right ] + \frac 1 {(2m+1)\pi +ik} $$

$$L=-\frac 1 {(2m+1)\pi +ik}\cdot \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}  e^{-((2m+1)\pi +ik)r} $$

Where

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}  e^{-((2m+1)\pi +ik)r}=\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}  e^{-(2m+1)\pi r}\cos(kr)-i\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}  e^{-(2m+1)\pi r}\sin(kr)=0-0$$

Regarding the first equation, take the second integral for example,

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{i k x}}{e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}} dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{i k x}}{e^{\pi x}}\cdot\frac{1}{1+e^{-2\pi x}} dx$$

For the term $\frac{1}{1+e^{-2\pi x}}$, do series expansion,

$$\frac{1}{1+e^{-2\pi x}}=\sum_{n=0}\left(-e^{-2\pi x}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}(-1)^ne^{-2\pi n x}$$

Comment: Thanks, I see now. How about the first equation though?

Comment: I add details for the first equation, you can use the similar way to deal with the first integral, but be careful for the first integral, its limit is from $-\infty$ to $0$, so you need to pull out $\frac{1}{e^{-\pi x}}$ and do the expansion for $\frac{1}{1+e^{2\pi x}}$. @mathematics-and-caffeine